# disable URL bar appearing on scroll up in mobile Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, navigation, scroll

I am implementing a mobile website, which has menu link and contact phone at the top of the page with CSS position:fixed.
Unfortunatelly, Chrome on iPhone has a behavior that when I scroll up, the Chrome URL bar appears at the top of the page over my menu and I have to scroll down or wait some 5 seconds for hiding the Chrome bar and accessing the menu again.

Is there some option to disable this mobile chrome behaviour or some workaround?

[image: Chrome bar hiding top menu]

Comment: Instead of disabling the default Chrome behaviour it would be best if the menu would simply stick to the bottom of the address bar chrome.

Comment: so you how would you do that ?

Comment: And then how would the user be able to go somewhere else (e.g. google.com) when they are viewing your page, if they cannot ever see the address-bar?